# Scott's trick without regularity

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

In ZF(C), one can easily get a class partition of $V$, we can even get an $\mathrm{Ord}$-partition using the Cumulative hierarchy: $P=\{V_{α+1}\setminus V_α\mid α∈\mathrm{Ord}\}$, such a partition let us do stuff like Scott's trick: given a class $A$, we can look at $A∩V_β$ where $β$ is the minimal $β$ so that intersection is not empty.

But the fact that $\bigcup P=V$ is equivalent to the axiom of regularity.

I remember somewhere reading that in $ZF\text{-regularity}$ we can't have Scott's trick like trick.

We can formulate Scott's trick as:

> There exists an $\mathrm{Ord}$-partition of $V$ (or equivalently - there exists cumulative hierarchy that sums up to the universe).

In a sense this version of Scott's trick is a "global trick".

---

While the intuition tells me that $\text{regularity}$ does not follow from this version of Scott's trick, is this true?

Comment: The “local Scott’s trick” as formulated here is trivially provable for every $\varphi$ (that is, ST holds): if $\{x:\varphi(x,x_1,\dots)\}=\emptyset$, put $S_\varphi(x_1,\dots)=\emptyset$, otherwise pick $x$ such that $\varphi(x,x_1,\dots)$ and put $S_\varphi(x_1,\dots)=\{x\}$.

Comment: To see that GST is strictly weaker than regularity, GST holds if the universe equals the cumulative hierarchy over a set of Quine atoms. If the set of atoms is nonempty, the axiom of regularity fails. This is all consistent relative to ZF.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek oops, that is embarrassing lol

Comment: @EmilJeřábek do you know if Quine atoms consistent with global choice? I can't see why they would fail, but still

Comment: You can take any model of ZFC and add a single Quine atom. This will not spoil global choice.

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with that, as already mentioned by James Hanson. Actually, I didn’t notice you consider global choice: note that global choice trivially implies GST right away.

Comment: Oh, but if you formulate it with a universal choice function rather than a bijection with Ord, it doesn’t, I guess.

Comment: I think the following version of Scott’s trick (weaker than GST, but stronger than your original ST) more closely resembles how it is used in practice: for any formula $\phi(x,x_1,\dots,x_n)$, there is a definable function $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ such that $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)\subseteq\{x:\phi(x,x_1,\dots,x_n)\}$, and if $\{x:\phi(x,x_1,\dots,x_n)\}\ne\emptyset$, then $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)\ne\emptyset$. This does follow from the existence of a global choice function.

Comment: Your definition of $P$ seems inside-out. You want $P$ to be the set of difference sets, not the set of ordinals.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I would encourage you to summarize your comments in an answer. I'm not exactly sure what the question is now.

Comment: @Joel: Are you claiming that $\rm Ord$ is a set??? Shocking! :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say $P$ is the class of difference sets, and to refer to the class of ordinals. (But @AsafKaragila, yes, Ord is a set, but in a larger universe!)

Comment: @Holo: Between "don't read this part, it's trivial" and strike-through text, maybe it's worth just rewriting the question to be clear? If someone wants to see the original, they can still do that.

Comment: If you have choice, then you can use Scott's trick well as regards cardinality is concerned, whether you have regularity or not. Scott's cardinals for example depends on Coret's principle that every set is of equal size to a well founded set, and this can hold even if Regularity fails. Cetainly it holds with Choice.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar What is Coret's  principle? I couldn't find anything on this online

Comment: @Holo, well I always see Thomas Forster mentioning it. It is the principle that every set is of the same size (bijective to) a well founded set. My speech however was generally connected to Scott's trick as applied to cardinality, so I don't know if there is a more general principle.

Comment: @Holo, see: https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2009-November/014196.html

Comment: @Holo, I think the requirement for having Scot trick for any $n$-ary relation $R$ is to have an $\mathrm{Ord}$-paritition of a subclass $K$ of $V$ such that for every set $x_1 \in V$ there exists sets $x_2,...,x_n \in K$ such that $x_1 \ R \ x_2,..,x_n$.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar thanks for the link, very interesting that axiom of choice can be treated as a weak form of foundation here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! Extend $\sf ZF - Reg.$ with the existence of a unique Quine atom $\sf Q=\{Q\}$, take $V$ to be the hierarchy over $\sf Q$, that is: $$\begin{align} & V_\emptyset = \sf Q \\ & V_{\alpha+1}= \mathcal P (V_{\alpha}) \\ & V_\lambda= \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} V_\alpha, \text {for limit } \lambda  \\ & V= \bigcup _{\alpha \in \mathrm{Ord}} V_\alpha \end {align}$$

clearly this $V$ has an $\mathrm{Ord}$-partition.